# Non English languages on Android simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to type something in Russian on a text field in my Android app in Android simulator. How can I do this? By default I can type only English. I tried to set Russian keyboard in settings, but this did not help. I think, it will be the same for other languages too. When I change a keyboard layout on my MacBook and try to type using MacBook keyboard, I can type only English letters. The same is for browser, when I try to type in Google search field something - I can't find out how to type Russian.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: P.S. my avd platform version is 4.0.3

Comment: Did you try change default Android language on the emulator? - Yes.

Comment: I don't mean the **keyboard** language/layout, but **Android locale**. [Check this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO9QYyRib5k&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: I solved problem for version 2.3.3 of Android and AVD. But for 4.0.3 not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not supported at all. Seems like you have to use custom View for the keyboard and implement the logic yourself. See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) for details. I have to mention there is even no Bulgarian keyboard included in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Install russian-keyboard_1.5.4_r70.apk from
http://acer-a500.ru/programs/927-programma-dlya-podderzhki-vneshney-usb-klaviatury.html

from command line (should be in the same directory as APK) 
adb install "russian-keyboard_1.5.4_r70.apk"

Enable the russian keyboard (in language settings) and select it as input method (after long press on any text enter field).

It also has Ukrainian :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change default Android language in the emulator? I don't mean the **keyboard** language/layout, but **Android locale**. [Check this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO9QYyRib5k&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: I think yes. Look at screenshot. Inside emulator everything is in Russian.

Comment: Tried changing your host OS locale?